# Classify manifolds up to diff homeomorphism v.s. the word problem for groups

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, cobordism

It is not possible to classify manifolds up to diffeomorphism or homeomorphism in dimensions ≥ 4 – because the word problem for groups cannot be solved. But it is possible to classify manifolds up to cobordism.

question 1: How does the word problem for groups affects classifying manifolds $M$ up to diffeomorphism or homeomorphism? Is that trouble of classifying manifold related to that the homotopy "group" ad winding numbers of sub-manifolds inside $M$ cannot be counted due to the word problem for groups?

question 2: Can the word problem for groups be solved? If so, can we classify manifolds up to diffeomorphism or homeomorphism in any dimensions, including dimensions ≥ 4?

Comment: Given a finitely presented group, there is an algorithmic process to construct a 4 (or higher) dimensional manifold with that given fundamental group. If there were an algorithmic way to tell this apart from a simply connected manifold with the same homology/cohomology, you could solve the problem of deciding whether a finitely presented group is trivial.

Comment: I'm confused about what you know versus what you ask. In your opening paragraph you state, correctly, "the word problem for groups cannot be solved". But then in question 2 you ask "Can the word problem for groups be solved?"

Comment: @MikeMiller What you say is not entirely correct. Given a presentation of a group there are a pair of 4-manifolds which are diffeomorphic when and only when the presentation is of the trivial group. The construction is not at all obvious. The only when part is critical as the homeomorphism problem for 2-complexes is decidable. Unfortunately there is lots of misinformation available on this problem on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

There is a theorem due to A.A. Markov regarding this question (the son of the much more famous A.A. Markov) available in the proceedings of the 1958 ICM. I'll try and give a modern proof in the smooth category in dimension four.

> Theorem (Markov): For any finite presentation $P$, there exists a pair of smooth closed orientable 4-manifolds $M_1$ and $M_2$ which are diffeomorphic if and only if $P$ presents the trivial group.

Proof: Assume $P$ has $m$ generators $a_1, \dots , a_m$ and $n$ relations $r_1, \dots ,r_n$. Consider $X$ the connect sum of $m$ copies of $S^1 \times S^3$. The fundamental group of $X$ is the free group on $m$ generators so we can represent the relations $r_1, \dots, r_n$ as elements of $\pi_1(X)$. By standard tranversality theory (for instance see Guillemin and Pollack), we can represent $r_1, \dots, r_n$ as disjoint simple closed curves. After surgering out neighborhoods of these curves (replacing their tubular neighborhoods $S^1 \times D^3$ each with an $D^2 \times S^2$) we get a smooth closed 4-manifold $X'$ where $P$ presents $\pi_1(X')$. After perhaps connecting summing with $\Bbb CP^2 \# -\Bbb CP^2$ we can assume $X'$ has indefinite and odd intersection form, hence its intersection form is determined by its signature, rank and parity.

A theorem of Wall implies then that if $X'$ is simply connected $X'$ is h-cobordant to $k_1\Bbb CP^2 \# k_2(-\Bbb CP^2)$ for some $k_1$ and $k_2$, and another theorem of Wall implies that for any two h-cobordant 4-manifolds $X_1$ and $X_2$, there exists an integer $N$ so that $X_1 \# N(S^2 \times S^2)$ is diffeomorphic to $X_2 \# N(S^2 \times S^2)$. In the case we are in we can actually find an explicit $N$ using the data of the presentation ($N$ just needs to be larger than the Morse number of $X'$), but I won't prove that here. Finally we let $M_1= X' \# N(S^2\times S^2)$ and $M_2=k_1\Bbb CP^2 \# k_2(-\Bbb CP^2) \# N(S^2 \times S^2)$.